# Aplicacion de android no se ejecuta en la API 19

Tags: java, android, sql-server-2014

Estoy empezando a desarrollar en Android y uso el IDE Android Studio. Tengo una app que se conecta a una base de datos con SQLServer, lo unico que hace es hacer una consulta que recibe 4 campos mandandole 1 ID. La App ya esta lista y la he porbado en el emulador con las versiones de android 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, pero con la 4.4 (API 19) al presionar el boton que ejecuta la consulta la aplicacion se cierra.

Codigo de conexion:

```
public Connection conexionBD() {
        Connection conexion = null;
        try{
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.10:1433;databasename=speedex;user=usuario;password=123;");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return conexion;
    }
```

Codigo de consulta:

```
public boolean consultarProyecto() {

        paquete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPaquete);
        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);

        envio = paquete.getText().toString();

        boolean resp = false;
        try{ //Realizar consulta SELECT
            String sql = "SELECT es.estado, en.fechaLlegada, t.transporte, en.precioTotal FROM estado es, envio en, medioTransporte t, paquete p, grupoPaquete g WHERE es.estadoId = en.estadoId AND t.transporteId = en.transporteId AND g.paqueteId = p.paqueteId AND en.grupoId = g.grupoId AND p.paqueteId = ?;";
            PreparedStatement cmd = conexionBD().prepareStatement(sql);
            //Llenar los parametros de la clase
            cmd.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(envio));
            //Ejecutar la consulta
            //pedira importar la clase ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = cmd.executeQuery();
            //Recorrer la lista de registros
            if(rs.next()){
                resp = true;
                //asignandole a los atributos de la clase

                estado = rs.getString(1);
                fecha = rs.getString(2);
                transporte = rs.getString(3);
                precio = rs.getDouble(4);

            }
            //cerrando conexion
            cmd.close();
            conexionBD().close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Consulta exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

El activity principal manda los datos al segundo Activity:

```
public void llamarSegundoActiviy(View view) {

        consultarProyecto();
        System.out.println("El estado es " + estado + "/n" + "La fecha es " + fecha + "/n" + "El tipo de transporte es " + transporte + "/n" + "El precio es " + precio);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ESTADO", estado);
        intent.putExtra("FECHA", fecha);
        intent.putExtra("TRANSPORTE", transporte);
        intent.putExtra("PRECIO", precio);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

El boton tiene el evento `OnClick` que llama al metodo anterior.
Y este es el codigo del segundo Activity

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView estado, fecha, transporte, precio;
    Integer numPaquete;
    String estado1, fecha1, transporte1;
    Double precio1;

    DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        estado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEstado);
        fecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
        transporte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTransporte);
        precio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);

        Intent inten = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = inten.getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            estado1 = extras.getString("ESTADO");
            estado.setText(estado1);

            fecha1 = extras.getString("FECHA");
            fecha.setText(fecha1);

            transporte1 = extras.getString("TRANSPORTE");
            transporte.setText(transporte1);

            precio1 = extras.getDouble("ESTADO");
            precio.setText(String.valueOf(formato.format(precio1)));
        }

        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El numero de paquete no existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ScrollingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cuál será el problema si corre en las demas versiones de android? ¿Habrá algo más que tenga que configurar?

**Actualizacion:** Añado el codigo del Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="andresk21.com.speedex">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Y el error que me da el logcat:

```
09-26 02:55:52.186 2500-2500/andresk21.com.speedex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: andresk21.com.speedex, PID: 2500
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore
                                                                         at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:359)
                                                                         at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
                                                                         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
                                                                         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
                                                                         at andresk21.com.speedex.MainActivity.conexionBD(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                         at andresk21.com.speedex.MainActivity.consultarProyecto(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                                         at andresk21.com.speedex.MainActivity.llamarSegundoActiviy(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
09-26 02:55:52.186 1561-1715/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity andresk21.com.speedex/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Mira el logcat que te dice exactamente lo que fallo y publicalo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta el código de tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: En este momento los añado

Comment: Creo que no es por la versión tienes un error general en la app

Comment: Pero en las demas versiones siguientes  no se da el error